# extracting directory name and putting it on top of the list

Tags: unix, sed, awk, ksh

```
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.x
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.kbd
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.x
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.kbd
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong3.kbd
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/whatisSPEC
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/ctx.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/sos.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dt.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/timexpr.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpusw.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpu.err.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dbr.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/psi.err.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/stapo.3
```

Hi guys,

I would like to know if there are any ways to insert the `directory name` to the top and reprint the list to make it look like this. Thanks so much.

```
TONE
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.x
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.kbd
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.x
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.kbd
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong3.kbd
man
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/whatisSPEC
man3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/ctx.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/sos.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dt.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/timexpr.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpusw.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpu.err.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dbr.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/psi.err.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/stapo.3
```

Comment: How are you getting the list in first place?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where you get your list from, so I make the same assumption as [Mari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20188286/1945981)

```
$ cat sample.txt
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.x
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.kbd
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.x
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.kbd
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong3.kbd
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/whatisSPEC
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/ctx.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/sos.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dt.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/timexpr.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpusw.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpu.err.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dbr.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/psi.err.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/stapo.3
```

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can handle this:

```
$ awk -f script.awk sample.txt
> TONE
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.x
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.kbd
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.x
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.kbd
> Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong3.kbd
> man
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/whatisSPEC
> man3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/ctx.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/sos.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dt.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/timexpr.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpusw.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpu.err.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dbr.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/psi.err.3
> Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/stapo.3
```

and the `script.awk` used in this example looks like:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="/"
}
lastDir!=$(NF-1){
    lastDir=$(NF-1)
    print lastDir
}
{
    print $0
}
```

At the beginning we set the field separator `FS` to `/`, this is the same as calling [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with `awk -F "/"` but for reasons of clarity I put everything in a script, instead of just an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) oneliner.

The `NF` variable gives you the number of fields per line, $(NF-1) is therefore the last field (separated by `/`) in every line and this is exactly the name of the directory. Now we compare, if the `lastDir` variable is *not* the same as the `$(NF-1)` (which is the current directory), then we overwrite the `lastDir` variable and print it. In any case, we print the whole line with `$0`. Note that the `lastDir` variable doesn't need to be initiated, it is simply set to an empty string.

Comment: Shorten some: `awk -F/ 'f!=$(NF-1) {f=$(NF-1);print f} 1' file`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input data is in a file. So I have created a file with your input data. So it comes like this in my server.

**cat sample.txt**

```
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.x
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong1.kbd
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.x
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong2.kbd
Aug 1 2013 /home/s/tone/TONE/gong3.kbd
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/whatisSPEC
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/ctx.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/sos.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dt.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/timexpr.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpusw.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/mpu.err.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/dbr.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/psi.err.3
Oct 10 2013 /home/s/man/man3/stapo.3
```

So you can get the directory names from this command,

```
awk -F "/" '{print $(NF-1)}' sample.txt | uniq
```

**output**

```
TONE
man
man3
```

Here am helping you to get the directory name only. Am not sure how to print them at top of each group lines.

Comment: Thanks alot guys! Appreciate all the inputs :)